# How to determine correct site for question?

Tags: discussion, migration, migrated-questions, redirection

When I am looking for an answer that I can't find with a search engine or by asking friends, I typically post on StackExchange.

If I am not sure which site is the most appropriate for my question, should I just take a best guess and post there, knowing it might possibly be moved to a more fitting site (but possibly not)?

For example, my present question is: *Can someone please post, in as much detail as possible, which AAC audio profile and bitrate Quicktime X utilizes during an export on OS X Mavericks (10.9) when choosing File > Export > Audio Only...*

Should this go on Superuser because it has to do with encoding technicals and bitrate, or should it go on AV Production because it has to do with audio, or should it go on Ask Different because it has to do with QTX on Mavericks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: either could work. The question is about "computer software," as in the SuperUser site scope, and is also about "Apple software," as in the Ask Different scope. There is site overlap. This means that questions may be valid on multiple sites.

As such, it is up to you to figure out which you think you would receive the best response on. Since this is primarily about the technical aspect of Quicktime X, I would personally recommend SuperUser. However, the question is valid on both.

Long story short: it's up to you. When in doubt, check the site's on-topic help page [(Ask Different,](https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) [SuperUser)](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

A generic answer:

- Check the applicable sites' on-topic (at `{site}/help/on-topic`, [example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)) pages.
- If still in doubt, check the applicable sites for similar questions.

  Take the results with a pinch of salt - questions aren't necessarily asked where they best fit. Stack Overflow, for example, has plenty of questions that would be better suited for Programmers or CS, mainly because it has so many questions, users aren't sure enough to merge and/or close them, it predates the other sites and it's better-known.
- If still in doubt, ask on a Meta site.

  - You can ask here, on Meta Stack Overflow, although there may be some speculation in the answers - we're not the experts on the scope of other sites.
  - You can ask on the Meta site of one of the applicable sites, which should be able to tell you `"Yes, this is appropriate for this site."` or `"No, this is not appropriate for this site"`, although possibly not with certainty `"This would be appropriate for the other site you're wondering about"`.

    If you wish to ask it there, it would perhaps be more appropriate to focus on `"Is this appropriate for this site"`, perhaps with a `"Or would it be better suited on that site"` footnote, as opposed to `"Should this be here or there"`.

    You can also ask on the Meta site of one of the other applicable sites if you couldn't get a definitive answer.